# Updating text of a local QLabel as data is altered in C++

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following code, which initializes a label to match an object's id.

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputVal; ++i)
{
     QLabel *newLabel = new QLabel(p0[i]->id, page);
     connect(p0, &Npc::setID, [&] 
          { newLabel->text() = p0[i]->id; });
     layout->addWidget(newLabel);
}
```

I'm trying to use the above `connect` to refresh the value of the label any time I change the value of the object's id. However, this doesn't work due to the label going out of scope and its value becoming inaccessible. Is there any way to access the label's value without declaring it outside of this scope?

This also hinges on the slot executing after the signal function does, which I would assume is the case. If it's not, is there any other way to update dynamic labels as object values change?

Comment: Could you clarify which of those I'm not satisfying?

Comment: The p0 is an arbitrary object with a data member 'id', like I said in the question. The location of the code fragment, as far as I can tell, is irrelevant, since I'm asking about a problem specific to the scope of the loop. I read the page you sent the first time, I just didn't see how it applied here.

Comment: And I explained why this already satisfied the conditions. Dmitry managed to answer the question well with the information I provided, so you don't need to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputVal; ++i)
{
    auto *obj = p0[i];
    QLabel *newLabel = new QLabel(obj->id, page);
    connect(obj, &Npc::setID, [obj, newLabel] 
        { newLabel->setText(obj->id); });
    layout->addWidget(newLabel);
}
```

Explanation: even though the **pointer** `newLabel` does indeed go out of scope after the loop iteration is finished, the actual `QLabel` it points to does not - it is created on the heap so it won't be deleted until something deletes it - in your case the layout would take care of it. So you can capture `newLabel` pointer by value (the address it points to would just be copied into the lambda) as well as the pointer to your object. You'd also need to use proper `setText` setter method of `QLabel` to assign new text to it; `text` method is a getter, it returns a copy of the text stored within the label, not a reference to it.

Comment: I was getting an access violation reading location when trying to set the text, so I just assumed that the label was out of memory and I couldn't use it. This makes sense though, thanks for the answer.